# I took one picture and my camera says memory full. Why does it say that?

Tags: troubleshooting, image-quality, memory-card, blur, sdcard

I just bought a Digital Camera 2.7k Ultra H. I took one picture and says that memory is full. I also set the date and time and nothing saves. I read the Users Manual twice and don't have a clue whats wrong with the camera. It also doesnt have great quality.

Comment: And photos now definitely don't save

Comment: Does it require a memory card?

Answer (score 7):

This camera requires an SD Card. You need to purchase a Secure Digital Memeory card and install this in the Camera. It may already have one installed. The SD card is the device that records and maintains the digital data that comprises the images you make.

If no SD card in installed, the camera likely can store one or perhaps two images.

If it already has a card, it may be too small and thus full or defective. If you install a new card, you must use the menu function "format". This action erases all data from the card and prepares the card to accept digital data in the native language of the camera's logic.

Buy and install one after consulting your manual as to card size.

Comment: "card size" is both a physical measure (standard, mini, or micro), as well as a digital capacity (16GB, 32GB, 64GB, etc). The physical aspect determines whether or not it will physically fit in the camera, while the digital capacity determines how many pictures it can hold (and if the camera can access the entire space available). #CoverAllTheBasics